# Hadoop mapred-site.xml 1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: xml, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to setup hadoop on a real cluster. I have this error when I start my hadoop cluster.
this is my mapred-site.xml file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
<value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
<value>hadoop-master:8021</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

I also tried with empty configuration, but without success.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are some weird characters, example `BOM` (Byte Order Mark) or white spaces at the beginning of your `mapped-site. xml`. Ideally `BOM` should not be present with `UTF-8` encoding as Java fails to parse such exception and gives above error. Please check if there are any characters in `mapped-site. xml` at the very beginning before `<?xml` and remove them if so. Also note that those characters might not be visible in all editors (depends on the encoding).